# CRM 2013 custom notification in the entity form

Tags: notifications, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to show custom warning message in entity from if specific field is not empty (on change).

I wrote in a different company global JS file the code that shows the message:

```
addNotification: function (message) { //Adds a warning message on the top of the entity Form

   var notificationHTML = '<DIV class="Notification"><TABLE cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"><TBODY><TR><TD vAlign="top"><IMG class="ms-crm-Lookup-Item" alt="" src="/_imgs/error/notif_icn_crit16.png" /></TD><TD><SPAN>' + message + '</SPAN></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV>';

   var notificationsArea = document.getElementById('Notifications');

   if (notificationsArea == null) return;

   notificationsArea.innerHTML += notificationHTML;

   notificationsArea.style.display = 'block';
},
```

and in my entity JS file I wrote this:

```
function checkIfAssignToIsEmpty() {
   var AssignTo = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('el_assign_to').getValue();

   if (AssignTo != null)
       newNotification();
}

function newNotification() {
    var assignToVal = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("el_assign_to").getValue();
    var newNotification = GlobalFunction.addNotification('assiignToVal + The Task will assign to');
}
```

I get error message after I choose value in my field

> Object doesn't support property or method 'addNotification'

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the supported methods for notification

```
Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification(message, level, uniqueId);
```

and

```
Xrm.Page.ui.clearFormNotification(uniqueId);
```

There are also notification for the controls. You can find several examples here:
http://garethtuckercrm.com/2013/10/17/crm-2013-new-features-javascript-notifications/